# Bdmo 2014 question?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, decimal-expansion

$N$ is a number that consists of $2012$ digits. If you take any consecutive $m$ digits $(m \leq 2012)$ from $N$ starting from any position in that number, there'll be another position in $N$ so that the $m$ consecutive digits starting from that position will be in the reverse order of the former one. The total number of possible values of $N$ can be written as $a \times 10^{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, $a$ is not divisible by $10$. What is the value of $a+b$?

It's a problem from BdMO 2014. I have no idea about how to approach this kind of problems (because I'm a beginner). Please help me solve it. And sorry if it's too easy.

---

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @baronjary see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/1062486

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry sir . I can not progress on this question ,  Cause I am very beginner . I found this question from a counting book?

Comment: N can be a number with all identical digits or alternating identical digits. There should be $90$ such numbers possible. So answer is $10$.

Comment: @sku sir can please explain?

Comment: @baronjary can you tell me the source of this problem? I couldnt find it in bdmo 2014. What is the counting book you mention? thanks

Comment: It's from BdMO 2012 Dinajpur and Kushtia contest. Author's answer suggests that "another position" means "the same or another position" and $N$ must satisfy problem statement at any $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N$ must satisfy problem statement at any $m\leq 2012$. None number $N$ can satisfy this problem statement is we understand "another position" as "not the same position", then let understand "another position" as "some position" (Problem statement 1). Another option is consider "another position" as "not the same position" but change $m\leq 2012$ (impossible) to $m\leq 2011$ (Problem statement 2). These problem statements are equivalent.

In problem statement 1 $N$ must be palindromic to satisfy case $m=2012$. In problem statement 2 $N$ must be palindromic to satisfy case $m=2011$. Palindromic $N$ will satisfy all cases $m\leq 2011$ in both problem statements.

Then one needs only calculate count of possible palindromic numbers $N$ with 2012 digits. That is the same as count of 1006-digit numbers (I suppose first digit of $N$ cannot be zero), which is $10^{1006}-10^{1005}=9\cdot 10^{1005}$. Then $a+b=1014$.